# Render html from a db field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my django project I have a model with a field that contain html code as text:

```
html_test = models.TextField()
```

for example in this field could be:

```
<html>
    <header><title>This is title</title></header>
    <body>
        Hello world
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to retrive this code and render dynamically showing the corresponding html page without create a file or save it on disk.
How can i render an html code in memory for display page and then destroy it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If it's in your field already, why can't you just display it?

Comment: ..the problem is, how can i display the html page from my data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what your actual question is. You retrieve the model from the db and return the data to the user, just like anything else. For example, a view might look like this:

```
def my_view(request, pk):
    obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return HttpResponse(obj.html_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jinja2 as the [templating engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/),

```
class YourClassName(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'your_template.jinja'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['html_data'] = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk).html_test
        return super(YourClassName, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

In your your_template.jinja

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
    {{html_data}}
</body>
```